# emplace unique_ptr in list

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I am trying to emplace an `std::unique_ptr` into a `std::list`, but it's failing with the following error:

```
<source>:29:23: error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::list<std::unique_ptr<test> >::emplace(std::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<test>&>::type)'
   29 |     mapList[1].emplace(std::move(t));
```

Following is the code:

```
using namespace std;

class test {
public:
    int i;
};


typedef std::list<std::unique_ptr<test>> testList;
int main() {
    unordered_map<int, testList> mapList;
    mapList.try_emplace(1, testList());
    std::unique_ptr<test> t = make_unique<test>();
    mapList[1].emplace(std::move(t));

  return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://godbolt.org/z/Wq4hPrzPj

Comment: Did you mean `emplace_back`?  `emplace` takes at least two parameters: a position, and then things that are passed to the constructor.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that.. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is quite explicit: There is no matching call for `std::list<>::emplace()` with the arguments you provided.

Indeed, if we look carefully at the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace), we notice that `std::list<>::emplace()` takes a position as first argument (given through a `std::list<>::const_iterator`).

In your case, since the list is empty, what you probably wanted was either `std::emplace_back()` or `std::emplace_front()`.

When in doubt, always refer to a good documentation.

---

***Sidenote:*** You should really get rid of that bad `using namespace std;` habit.
You can see more information on the topic here: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).